# Airflow DAG folder is not visible

Tags: ubuntu, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have just installed Airflow in ubuntu and I am following tutorials to create DAGs. After successfully installing airflow I have created `dags` folder in airflow home and created a sample DAG file as `sample.py`. But I actually don't see the dags folder

```
yash@DESKTOP-TUTMG4J:~/airflow$ ls -l
total 316
-rw-rw-rw- 1 yash yash      0 Jun 12 19:26 airflow-webserver.err
-rw-rw-rw- 1 yash yash    140 Jun 12 19:29 airflow-webserver.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 yash yash    222 Jun 12 19:29 airflow-webserver.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 yash yash      5 Jun 13 14:53 airflow-webserver.pid
-rw-rw-rw- 1 yash yash  36462 Jun 12 17:02 airflow.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 yash yash 270336 Jun 13 14:54 airflow.db
drwxrwxrwx 1 yash yash    512 Jun 12 21:57 logs
-rw-rw-rw- 1 yash yash   2578 Jun 12 17:02 unittests.cfg
yash@DESKTOP-TUTMG4J:~/airflow$
```

But when I start the `airflow webserver` it says `Filling up the DagBag from /home/yash/airflow/dags`

```
yash@DESKTOP-TUTMG4J:~/airflow$ airflow initdb
DB: sqlite:////home/yash/airflow/airflow.db
[2020-06-13 14:51:35,133] {db.py:378} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
Done.
yash@DESKTOP-TUTMG4J:~/airflow$ airflow webserver
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
[2020-06-13 14:53:22,260] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2020-06-13 14:53:22,260] {dagbag.py:396} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/yash/airflow/dags
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================
[2020-06-13 14:53:23 +0530] [5308] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.0
[2020-06-13 14:53:23 +0530] [5308] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (5308)
[2020-06-13 14:53:23 +0530] [5308] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-06-13 14:53:23 +0530] [5313] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5313
[2020-06-13 14:53:23 +0530] [5314] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5314
[2020-06-13 14:53:23 +0530] [5315] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5315
[2020-06-13 14:53:23 +0530] [5327] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5327
[2020-06-13 14:53:23,678] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2020-06-13 14:53:23,679] {dagbag.py:396} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/yash/airflow/dags
[2020-06-13 14:53:23,836] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2020-06-13 14:53:23,837] {dagbag.py:396} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/yash/airflow/dags
[2020-06-13 14:53:23,949] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
```

and ofcourse I don't see my DAG in airflow UI as well. Can someone enlighten me what I am doing wrong and how can airflow pick my DAGS from the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you actually didn't create the `dags` directory in Airflow's home. Airflow's home in your case is `/home/yash/airflow/` and there is obviously no `dags` directory there.

The Airflow's log message `Filling up the DagBag from /home/yash/airflow/dags` may be somewhat misleading. It actually means that Airflows is looking for DAG scripts under that path, but it does not mean that the path exists.

Create the directory:

```
mkdir /home/yash/airflow/dags
```

and try creating a DAG script again.

Comment: just for FYI or someone who visits this later, though I have created a file in correct path from Windows that didn't show up in the bash terminal. The reason being that "copying files or creating files directly into the Linux subsystem from Windows is not supported". More on this can be read [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/402#issuecomment-220585695)